# Tkinter: 'after" function is still called after root has been destroyed

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter

I am new to Python and I am trying to create a Restaurant simulation with Tkinter as my GUI (Since it is easy).

I have a Timer that uses function called `Tick()` (shown below:)

```
def Tick(self,time,type,resto,foodname,Database):
    if self.cookTimer.winfo_exists() is 1:
        .....
        else:
            if self.cookTimer.winfo_exists() is 1:
                self.timeLabel.configure(text="%d" %time)
                self.cookTimer.after(1000, lambda: self.Tick(time,type,resto,foodname,Database))
        self.cook.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", lambda: self.Callback(self.cook,resto,Database))
```

What I am trying to do is before exiting the program, it will ask the user Yes or No first.
Now, in `Tick()`, the root is named `self.cookTimer`.

When the user already exited the `self.cookTimer`, `self.timeLabel.configure` is still running thus raising an error that `configure` needs the root.

Can anyone help me by telling me how to make the program NOT run `configure` if `cookTimer` is destroyed?

Comment: Please do tell me if you do not comprehend my question.
I am new to this Questioning-site when it comes to Code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Tkinter `after` method returns an identifier that can be used to cancel the scheduled call if it turns out you do not need it any more. A good example of this is setting up a timeout call. If your code completes within the timeout then you cancel the timeout. In your example, when you setup the after call, record the result and use that to cancel the call:

```
self.after_id = self.cookTimer.after(1000, lambda: ...)
....
self.after_cancel(self.after_id)
```

You might want to create a cleanup method and have the WM_PROTOCOL_DELETE and other termination calls all go there to cleanup and exit.

Comment: I apologize for being dumb but I cannot think of how to apply your example to my code.

What should I do with `self.after_id`? It is just a number that increases, right?

Comment: The after call returns an identifier for the scheduled event. All you can do with it is pass it to the `after_cancel` method to cancel the event. So when you handle WM_DELETE_WINDOW, cancel the after event as well as doing your other callback stuff.